# how to switch SharePoint 2010 master page for logged in user

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to switch Sharepoint 2010 depending on the logged in user?

an example :

I want to make "mycustompage.master" as master page for users in group "mysiteowners" and "v4.master" as master page for the rest of users.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To set the master page file, use the following code

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(UserIsInMySiteOwners())
    {
        Page.MasterPageFile = "~/mycustompage.master";
    }
    else
    {
        Page.MasterPageFile = "~/v4.master";
    }

}
```

(You'll have to define your own method to determine if the user is in "Mysiteowners")

Comment: thanks for ur help but I tried to do that and nothing changed

Comment: @Mazen - where are you running the code?  A web part, page...?

Comment: I created Class Library project, install the out put dll in GAC and register the dll in my SharePoint webconfig.